# Navigate to Home page of a community from different community in the same tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

I am trying to navigate to home page of a community when a button is clicked which is in another community. I am able to navigate to the page but it opens in a new tab since I have used `standard__webPage` as type. Is there a way to open it in the same tab.

```
    var pageReference = {
        "type": "standard__webPage",
        "attributes": {
           "url": url // this url has the url value
          }
    };
    var navService = component.find("navService");
    event.preventDefault();
    navService.navigate(pageReference);
```

Comment: did u try ` type: "comm__namedPage" ` instead of `standard__webPage`

Comment: I think it only navigates to page of the same community